# tengo este Error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of null

Tags: javascript, funciones, formularios

estoy creando un Control de Ingreso y Salida de Funcionarios,  el cual posee un Formulario de Registro para alimentar una base de datos,  al momento de diligenciar el formulario y oprimir el botón "guardar" me aparece esto en consola y no almacena los datos en la bd, soy principiante en el tema, busco la manera de poder generar alguna solucion ya que lo estoy realizando solo, es bastante basico pero yo se que va a ser de mucha ayuda para la compañia para la cual laboro:

registro.js:37 Error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style')
at registro.js:31:28

registro.js:60 Error en la verificación: TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style')
at registro.js:55:30

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Registro de Empleados</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/formulario.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
   <h1>Registro de Empleados</h1>

   <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="registroForm" onsubmit="return validarYEnviar(event)">
     <label for="codigo">Código:</label>
     <input type="text" id="codigo" class="codigo-de-barras" name="codigo" required style="font-family: 'Code128', sans-serif;" autocomplete="off">
     <label for="nombre">Nombre Completo:</label>
     <input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre" required autocomplete="off">
     <label for="cedula">Número de Cédula:</label>
     <input type="text" id="cedula" name="cedula" required autocomplete="off">
     <label for="cargo">Cargo:</label>
     <input type="text" id="cargo" name="cargo" required autocomplete="off">
     <label for="foto">Fotografía:</label>
     <input type="file" id="foto" name="foto" accept="image/*" required>
     <button type="submit">Guardar</button><br><hr>
     <a href="../index.php">Inicio</a>
   </form>

   <div id="successMessage" class="success-message" style="display: none;">
   <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
   <p>¡Registro exitoso!</p>
</div>

<div id="errorMessage" class="error-message" style="display: none;">
   <i class="fas fa-times-circle"></i>
   <p>Error: Por favor complete todos los campos.</p>
</div>
 </div>

 <script src="../js/registro.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
const registroForm = document.getElementById('registroForm');
registroForm.addEventListener('submit', validarYEnviar);
});

function verificarRegistro() {
    const codigo = document.getElementById('codigo').value;
    return fetch('../php/verificar_empleado.php', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        },
        body: 'codigo=' + codigo
    })
    .then(response => {
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error('Error en la solicitud');
        }
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(data => {
        const successMessage = document.getElementById('successMessage');
        const warningMessage = document.getElementById('warningMessage');

        if (data.existe) {
            successMessage.style.display = 'block';
            warningMessage.style.display = 'none';
            return false;
        } else {
            successMessage.style.display = 'none';
            warningMessage.style.display = 'block';
            console.log('Empleado no registrado, se enviará el formulario.');
            return true;
        }
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error:', error);
        return false;
    });
}

function validarYEnviar(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    verificarRegistro()
        .then(validado => {
            const successMessage = document.getElementById('success');
            const errorMessage = document.getElementById('error');

            if (validado) {
                successMessage.style.display = 'block';
                errorMessage.style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById('registroForm').submit();
            } else {
                errorMessage.style.display = 'block';
                successMessage.style.display = 'none';
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('Error en la verificación:', error);
        });
}
```

```
    <?php
include 'conexion.php'; // Incluye el archivo de conexión

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    // Obtener datos del formulario
    $codigo = $_POST['codigo']; // Asegúrate de obtener el código del formulario
    $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
    $cedula = $_POST['cedula'];
    $cargo = $_POST['cargo'];

    // Consulta preparada para insertar datos de manera segura
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO empleados (codigo, nombre, cedula, cargo) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
    
    // Vincular parámetros
    $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $codigo, $nombre, $cedula, $cargo);

    // Ejecutar la consulta
    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        echo "Empleado registrado correctamente";
    } else {
        echo "Error al registrar el empleado: " . $stmt->error;
    }
    
    // Cerrar la declaración
    $stmt->close();
}

// Cerrar la conexión al finalizar las operaciones
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: no tienes ningún elemento con el ID 'warningMessage', al menos en el código expuesto aquí pues no se ve.

Comment: infinit3Loop__ muchas gracias, no me habia dado cuenta